# Is the neutral pi meson a relativistic electron positron pair?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, pions

Is the neutral [pi meson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) a relativistic electron positron pair? An electron position pair orbiting at relativistic speeds is proposed as a model of a neutral pi meson by Ernest Sternglass.  However, his mathematics is semi-classical. Has anybody done a QED approximation?

Comment: Are you talking about Bhabha scattering?

Comment: You should leave a link. The short answer is that any such models might be squeezed to fit a particular proposal, as this one, but will be unable to explain a multitude of similar data ( which the standard model does). This particular proposal is dead from the start because the electron and positron will disappear into photons, as has been seen experimentally with the positronium.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium . The invariant mass of the positronium is very much smaller than of the pi0 and no pi0s were seen in e+e- accelerator experiments .

Comment: dimension10: Sternglass believes that hadrons are made of electrons and positrons, not quarks. e.g. a proton is supposed to be a number of electron-positron pairs, plus a positron. This was his theory 50 years ago, before quarks were confirmed, and he still believes it (he's almost 90 now), and it looks like he has some fans in the world of "alternative physics".

Comment: The neutral pion is an up-antiup quark-antiquark pair's superposition with a down-antidown quark-antidown quark. All the charges of such a system cancel, they're zero, so they're just like those of the electron-positron pair. That's why electron-positron may appear as the final state of the pion decay. But that doesn't mean that it's the same thing. According to QFT, particles may be produced and destroyed as long as the relevant conservation laws are obeyed. A neutron decays to proton, electron, antineutrino which doesn't mean it's composed of them. There's a genuine transmutation going on.

Comment: Following is a link to Sternglass's 1961 paper,  published in the Physical Review Journal, re the possibility that a relativistic electron-positron pair might be the actual structure of the humble neutral pi-meson. https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.123.391

Answer (score 4):

The mass (a relativistic invariant quantity) of the $\pi^0$ is well measured and is not consistent with the mass of positronium (also well measured). By orders of magnitude, so no the neutral pion is not an electron positron pair.

Comment: Sternglass' model is NOT positronium.  Positronium is an electron-positron pair orbiting at non-relativistic speeds.  Sternglass showed, albeit semi-classically, that at relativistic speeds there are certain allowed orbits, the lowest (in energy) of which matches the mass and decay lifetime of the neutral Pi meson very well.

Comment: Such a model would have to assume some mechanics between those particles other than the classical electromagnetics. The positronium solutions are *complete* given classical interactions plugged into QM. There are no bound relativistic states. Worse, the spectrum of positronium agrees with expectations from plain old E&M+QM except where the modifications from QED show up. I'll grant that this was a reasonable thing to guess back in the day, but at some point it gets to be silly to stick with it.